# How to update data using custom key in firestore

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase firestore to save and retrieve data for my project. My diewstore is look like this ..[image]

I want to update the about data using the following onClick function

```
function updateAbout() {
  let key = "1";
  var aboutTextArea = document.getElementById("exampleInputTextAreaAbout1");
  db.collection("settings").doc(key).update({ 
    about: aboutTextArea.value,
   })
  .then(function () {
    console.log("updated");
    //location.reload();  //reload to load all the product
    //return false;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Update failed: ' + error.message);
  });
}
```

but this shows an error in console like the image
[image]

How can I use that custom key? please help!! I cannot manage to update my 'about' data. Actually I want to update the following field,in html is

```
<div class="main-content container-fluid">
                    <h2>About</h2>
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputTextAreaAbout1">About Description</label>
                        <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTextAreaAbout1" placeholder="Enter About" required></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updateAbout()">Update</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
db.collection("settings").doc(key).update(...)
```

Also see the documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document), which covers pretty much this use-case,.

Comment: Expanding on Frank's answer - .doc(key)  is not the document; it is a document REFERENCE (think of it as an index) to the document.  You have to execute some operation on this reference (.get(), .onSnapShot(), .set(), .update()) to actually access the document. doc().data(key) IS NOT a firestore operation of any kind.  you can only use .data() on the RESULT OF ONE OF THE FETCH OPERATIONS (.get(), .onSnapShot(), etc)

Comment: Kindly saw my edited question. I am getting the same error. Please help me

Comment: Please don't change your question after it's been answered. If you have a new problem, open a new question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).